# Draw two cards at random without replacement. What is the chance of not getting all kings?

Tags: probability, statistics, card-games

I am at a loss for how to solve this problem. Can someone please help and link the steps below? Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried finding the probability of getting all kings?

Comment: 1, because it's impossible to get all 4 kings by only drawing 2 cards.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to compute the chance you get two kings and subtract from $1$. What is the chance the first is a king? The second? Both?

Answer (score 1):

You want the probability for *not* obtaining *two from four* kings when selecting *two from fifty-two* cards without replacement or bias.

Use the law of complementary probability, and subtract from $1$ the probability for obtaining two kings.

Also recall that $\binom mn$ counts ways to select $n$ from $m$ things without replacement or bias.